OpenCV Include doesnt deliver references to cv Functions (undefined reference)
i just got started with c++ and have been trying to use OpenCV for an GUI.
I installed Cmake, Ninja and OpenCV into my C:/ directory. I now planned to Build the Project but i get an error in the Linking stage of Compilation.
Here is the log:
    [main] Building folder: opencvtest 
    [main] Configuring project: opencvtest 
    [proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -         DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -SC:/opencvtest -Bc:/     opencvtest/build -G Ninja
    [cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
    [cmake] -- Configuring done (0.2s)
    [cmake] -- Generating done (0.1s)
    [cmake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/opencvtest/build
    [build] Starting build
    [proc] Executing command: chcp
    [proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/opencvtest/build --    config Debug --target all --
    [build] [1/1 100% :: 0.205] Linking CXX executable opencvtest.exe
    [build] FAILED: opencvtest.exe 
    [build] C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\c++.exe -g  CMakeFiles/    opencvtest.dir/main.cpp.obj -o opencvtest.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libopencvtest.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -LC:/PROGRA~1/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib -lopencv_world4100d  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
    [build] C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/ bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles/opencvtest.dir/main.cpp.obj: in function `main':
    [build] C:/opencvtest/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat()'
    [build] C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/opencvtest/main.cpp:19: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::~Mat()'
    [build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    [build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
    [proc] The command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/opencvtest/build --config    Debug --target all -- exited with code: 1
    [driver] Build completed: 00:00:00.360
    [build] Build finished with exit code 1

My CMake List file looks like this (although i dont think the problem inherits from there):
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(opencvtest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

   # Specify the path to OpenCV headers
   include_directories("C:/Program Files/opencv/build/include")

   # Specify the path to OpenCV library directories
   link_directories("C:/Program Files/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib")

   # Add the executable
   add_executable(opencvtest main.cpp)

   # Link against the OpenCV libraries
   target_link_libraries(opencvtest opencv_world4100d)


And finally the main.cpp:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


int main(int argc, char** argv )
{

    cv::Mat image;
    /**image = imread("C:\\opencvtest\\1.jpg");
    if ( !image.data )
    {
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }**/
    //namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    //imshow("Display Image", image);
    //waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}

Thanks in advance
I`ve already checked the System variables (opencv_version outputs the version number)
Intelisense gets that the include is legid (if the lib folder is deletet it males Squiggles)

C:/Program Files/opencv/build/x64/vc16/lib are 64 bit binaries for Microsoft's msvc compiler and not compatible with MinGW so it's understandable that it didn't work. Use pacman to install the correct opencv binaries for your compiler.

"have been trying to use OpenCV for an GUI" -- what a terrible idea. OpenCV is a computer vision library, the GUI functionality provided is the least common denominator suitable for prototyping at best. | It also seems that you're using mingw g++ to compile your code, but are linking to OpenCV libraries built for Visual C++. AFAIK that won't work.

And pray tell, what's this thing about using MinGW on Windows these days?  The proper VIsual Studio has been free for ages, one of the best IDE's I've come across in over 2 decades, with a rather good C++ compiler. Why do people want to jump through such complex hoops while just beginning to learn?

A side note: your CMake is not compatible for Release build because it always links with opencv_world4100d (the suffix d for Debug build).

@DanMašek "open source" makes people feel warm and fuzzy and righteous, vs evil commercial software. also, software piracy these days appears to be more diseased (trojans) and less quality-controlled (more anonymous/transactional) than it was 20 years ago, so kids these days, having no money, rarely give themselves the five-finger discount, so they don't learn that commercial software is indeed more polished and more enjoyable to use.
